# Requirement in Oracle PL/SQL to update labels

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 2 tables - tab1 , tab2 with following data

```
tab1 data:
OID   Label
1     MX1
1     MX2
1     MX3
2     MX4
2     MX5


tab2 data:
OID  ID    Label
1    5678
1    2347
1    9687
2    4567
2    3455
```

The join condition between these two tables is oid column.I need to create a process which will update Label column from tab1 to Label column of tab2.It doesn't matter which label gets assigned to which record of tab2 for a particular oid. The only check that needs to happen is that both the tables should have same number of records for an oid.The final outcome should be the following

```
tab2 data:
OID  ID    Label
1    5678  MX1
1    2347  MX2
1    9687  MX3
2    4567  MX4
2    3455  MX5
```

Again, it doesn't matter which label gets assigned to tab2 for a particular oid,but the same label cannot be repeated for a particular oid.What would be the best way to write a code for this requirement?

Comment: So... what have you tried? What research have you done into Oracle's `UPDATE` statement?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sql solution:

```
merge into tab2 
using 
           (
            select t2."id" as ide,t1."label" labela from
            (select rownum n,"label","oid" from tab1 order by "oid")t1,
            (select rownum n, a2.* from tab2 a2 order by "oid")t2
            where t1.n=t2.n and
                  t1."oid"=t2."oid"
            ) tb4
on (tab2."id" = tb4.ide)
            when matched then 
                update set tab2."label" = tb4.labela;
```

Result:

```
oid| id | label
-----------------
1   5678    mx1
1   2347    mx2
1   9687    mx3
2   4567    mx4
2   3455    mx5
```

Comment: Excellent, Toni!

Answer (score 0):

Sample tables:

```
SQL> select * from tab1 order by oid, label;

       OID LAB
---------- ---
         1 mx1
         1 mx2
         1 mx3
         2 mx4
         2 mx5

SQL> select * from tab2 order by oid, id;

       OID         ID LAB
---------- ---------- ---
         1       2347
         1       5678
         1       9687
         2       3455
         2       4567

SQL>
```

This is query that returns desired result:

```
SQL> with
  2  t1 as (select oid, label, rowid rwid,
  3           row_number() over (partition by oid order by label) rn
  4         from tab1
  5        ),
  6  t2 as (select oid, id, rowid rwid,
  7           row_number() over (partition by oid order by id) rn
  8         from tab2
  9        )
 10  select b.oid, b.id, a.label
 11  from t1 a join t2 b on a.oid = b.oid and a.rn = b.rn;

       OID         ID LAB
---------- ---------- ---
         1       2347 mx1
         1       5678 mx2
         1       9687 mx3
         2       3455 mx4
         2       4567 mx5

SQL>
```

---

A few options I tried: **correlated update** won't work because of

> ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

```
SQL> update (
  2  with
  3  t1 as (select oid, label, rowid rwid,
  4           row_number() over (partition by oid order by label) rn
  5         from tab1
  6        ),
  7  t2 as (select oid, id, rowid rwid, label,
  8           row_number() over (partition by oid order by id) rn
  9         from tab2
 10        )
 11  select b.oid, b.id, b.label b_label, a.label a_label
 12  from t1 a join t2 b on a.oid = b.oid and a.rn = b.rn
 13  )
 14  set b_label = a_label;
set b_label = a_label
    *
ERROR at line 14:
ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table


SQL>
```

---

`MERGE` won't work because of

> ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view

```
SQL> merge into
  2           (select oid, id, label, row_Number() over (partition by oid order by id   ) rn from tab2) b
  3    using  (select oid,     label, row_number() over (partition by oid order by label) rn from tab1) a
  4    on (a.oid = b.oid and
  5        a.rn  = b.rn)
  6    when matched then update set
  7      b.label = a.label;
         (select oid, id, label, row_Number() over (partition by oid order by id   ) rn from tab2) b
         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view


SQL>
```

`Merge` would accept a view (created with `create view ...`), but a view has to be [updateable](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#CEGCADFA); this one can't be because it contains analytic function.

---

What's left is a PL/SQL procedure:

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (with
  3                    t1 as (select oid, label, rowid rwid,
  4                             row_number() over (partition by oid order by label) rn
  5                           from tab1
  6                          ),
  7                    t2 as (select oid, id, rowid rwid,
  8                             row_number() over (partition by oid order by id) rn
  9                           from tab2
 10                          )
 11                    select b.rwid, a.label
 12                    from t1 a join t2 b on a.oid = b.oid and a.rn = b.rn
 13                 )
 14    loop
 15      update tab2 b set
 16        b.label = cur_r.label
 17        where b.rowid = cur_r.rwid;
 18    end loop;
 19  end;
 20  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from tab2 order by oid, id;

       OID         ID LAB
---------- ---------- ---
         1       2347 mx1
         1       5678 mx2
         1       9687 mx3
         2       3455 mx4
         2       4567 mx5

SQL>
```

---

Maybe someone has another idea; I'd like to see it & learn something new.

Comment: You could use merge into tab2 if u generated the wanted result with 2 joined inline views.